# Error in Python import

Tags: python, python-3.x, package

I'm in the learning phase and I have a problem with `import`

I've created a module named test, the folder has my test.py, setup.py & python.exe, after running sdist and install, I got MANIFEST file, build, lib inside build & dist folders.

Now, I tried to make use of my module in IDLE and produced the following

```
>>> import test
>>> movies = ["1","2", ["3", "4", ["5", "6"]]]
>>> test.lol ()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    test.lol ()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'lol'
```

This is the error I'm getting. What went wrong? What was the problem? Since I'm new I couldn't find a solution myself.

This is my module :

```
def lol():
    for each_item in movies:
       if isinstance(each_item, list):
           for nest in each_item:
               print(nest)
       else:
           print(each_item)
```

I use Windows 7 machine and Python 3.2

Answer (score 1):

You are importing the `test` module from the standard library instead of the `test` module of your own.

For Python to be able to find the modules, they have to be located by the paths defined in `sys.path` list, e.g.:

```
import sys

# insert the path to the beginning of the list:
sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/my/test/module/directory')

# now Python importing system will search the directory defined above 
# before scanning the standard library dirs. 
import test
```

You can check the `sys.path` in IDLE via `File -> Path Browser`.